# Macros and Analyzing Images

Tags: java, c#, macros, autohotkey

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask a question like this. Please refer me elsewhere if I am wrong for posting here.

I am trying to implement a program that solves a lockpicking minigame. Here is a demonstration of the minigame: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qbjMwJtTxs&ab_channel=grantmartin

The way the minigame works is this: you move your mouse left and right to reposition and hold f to lockpick. The farther the lock rotates when lockpicking, the closer you are to the "sweet spot". The size of this "sweet spot" depends on the type of lock you are picking (basic, medium, or advanced). Once you fully rotate the lock on the sweet spot, the lock unlocks and you complete the minigame. However, if you run out of time or your lockpick breaks (this happens if you hold f too many times or for too long on places where it cant rotate further), you lose the minigame.

My plan for implementing this is as follows:

Use a macro to tap f at the very left part of the lock. If the lock does not rotate, move the mouse to the right a particular amount. This amount depends on the lock being picked, for it will be slightly less than the size of the "sweet spot". Continue moving the mouse right and tapping f until the lock rotates some.

Once a spot where the lock rotates is found, measure how far it rotates at that spot. Given this amount, there should exist an equation that tells me exactly how far I need to move the mouse to land on the "sweet spot". I will find this equation through trial and error/tweaking. Once the amount is equated from the equation, the script will first try moving the mouse the equated amount to the right. If this makes it worse (doesn't rotate as much), the script will try the left side. This should successfully solve the minigame.

In order to track the rotation/position of the lock, I will use a C# or Java dll (only two languages I know well) that constantly takes screenshots of the application. From the screenshot, I will need to somehow find the position of the lock, preferably by tracking the top right corner of the keyhole. This is one place where I need implementation suggestions.

In order to move the mouse and press f, I will use a macro scripting language, such as AutoHotKey. This script will handle the moving at a particular increment to the right, and will call methods in the Java/C# dll in order to know when to stop (when it begins to rotate). Once it finds a spot that it rotates, the Java/C# dll will be called to find out how much it has rotated. Once we have this amount (will probably be in degrees), It will be plugged into a magic equation that tells me how far I need to move to hit the sweet spot. The script will then be told to move this distance.

Here is where I need help:

Am I overcomplicating any implementation method? Is there something simpler I am missing?

What is the best way to track the rotation of the lock? How would I go about doing it? If my method seems suitable, how would I generally implement it?

What is the fastest way to take screenshots? Implementations I have tried so far have taken at least 40 ms per screenshot. This is probably plenty (about 25 fps), but I am scared that the whole process of analyzing the images will slow it down considerably.

What is the most precise way to macro the incremented movements?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated :)

tl;dr

I am trying to create a macro that solves this minigame: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qbjMwJtTxs&ab_channel=grantmartin

I need implementation suggestions on how to do so.

Edit: Any information AT ALL is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I would think that solving this kind of problem by analyzing images would probably be more cumbersome than patching the executable to remove the minigame.

Comment: @JonasH I do not have access to the executable source code

Comment: There are various ways to decompile, debug, and patch binary code, that would be difficult, but so would setting up an image analyzing pipeline.